# Трехзвенная архитектура против клиент-БД

Tags: архитектура, c++, sql

Здравствуйте.

**Дано:**

- есть толстый клиент. Содержащий в себе чуть-чуть бизнес-логики, которой бы ему не знать.
- есть БД с "интерфейсом" в виде хранимых процедур, которые реализуют много бизнес-логики. Есть интерфейс для клиента и интерфейс для сервера.
- есть недосервер, который не выполняет функции сервера в полном смысле, но выполняет часть функций, которые не могут выполняться хранимыми процедурами. Есть интерфейс для клиента.

Толстый клиент, соответственно, взаимодействует напрямую и с БД (в части манипуляции данными) и с несервером (в части получения функций там реализованных). Недосервер так же взаимодействует с БД для манипуляции данными и с клиентом (один из вариантов взаимодействия с клиентом - публикатор-подписчик).

**Задача:**

Нужно реализовать новые функции системы. Делать это можно несколькими способами, при этом оценка в часах в обоих случаях получается примерно равной.

1. Реализовать все новое в хранимых процедурах на
       стороне БД и некоторые функции на
       стороне клиента, не трогать сервер
2. Реализовать все новое на стороне сервера, незначительно касаясь и хранимых процедур (в части увеличения вариантов представления данных), и клиента (в части отображения новых функций).

**Проблема**

Мое интуитивное "как лучше" говорит, что правильно двигаться в сторону классической трехзвенки, соответственно, не нагружая клиент и БД новыми функциями, но нагружая сервер. А по возможности, если часы будут позволять, то и разгрузить БД и клиент от бизнес-логики, которая им не нужна. Но даже если это не удастся сделать, все равно лучше двигаться в этом направлении.

*Лобби агрессивных базистов-ораклисто-мсскуэльников* считает, что все надо делать первым вариантом.

И тут в дело вступает аргументация. Какие плюсы и минусы есть у этих вариантов? Чем трехзвенка лучше, а чем хуже взаимодействия клиент-база? Может быть, моё чутье меня подводит?

**Аргументы, которые я нашел**

- безопасность. Трехзвенка позволит теоретически вообще перекрыть доступ к БД со стороны клиентской машины, таким образом, обезопасив эту БД. Клиент-база нет.
- масштабируемость. В случае увеличения количества БД или серверов, клиент, не имеющий прямой связи с данными, может ничего не знать об их устройстве и организации. Максимум, что ему надо будет знать - адреса других серверов. Клиент-база нет, и там придется или серьезно допиливать логику клиента, или формировать db-link-ки и допиливать логику "правильной" БД, формируя иерархию БД.
- производительность. Возможность масштабирвания дает возможность существенно влиять на производительность.

Что-то еще? Или что-то написанное - высосано из пальца?
Заранее благодарю.

**Обновление**

Сервер был нужен, потому что есть сеть "сборщиков информации", аккумуляцию данных с которых разумно делать на сервере. Затем эта информация должна попасть в БД, а при наличии подписки со стороны клиента на некоторую информацию, клиент должен быть уведомлен о ее получении. То, что намудрили - да, и это очевидно. То, что по идее сервер должен нести на себе бизнес-логику - да, но вот почему?

**Обновление 2**

Бизнес-логику из клиента можно перенести не в сервер, а в хранимые процедуры. Мне вот сейчас коллега подсказал, что запросы в базу с JOIN-ами экспоненциально могут увеличивать нагрузку, и один запрос к базе с 3мя join может стоить дороже по времени и нагрузке, чем 3 запроса в базу и управление выгруженным на стороне сервера в оперативке.

Comment: @smallFish хотите оставить за сервером лишь аккумуляцию и оповещения?

Comment: @smackmychi, нет, хочу подобрать набор аргументов, который бы переубедил агрессивное лобби базистов так, чтобы они не остались обиженными, когда я скажу, что будем делать сервер.

Comment: Вы не описали объемы. Если три человека вбивают по два документа в день, то тут и "эксель" справится... Трехзвенка легко масштабируется, правда, но ради трех клиентов поднимать возможно выделенные серваки - пахнет распилом. :)

Comment: @Yura Ivanov щас с распилом не так все просто. Мб просто люди не стали вдаваться в детали.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, речь же идет об архитектуре софта, а не ПАК-а. Да и распиливают обычно, не спрашивая команду разработчиков. )

Comment: @smackmychi, ну вот есть пример: 1С. Файловая база и трехзвенка. И тот и другой варианты работают на одних и тех же конфигурациях. Стоимость внедрения отличается на два, иногда на три порядка. 1Сники даже базу знаний завели по "технологическим вопросам крупных внедрений", с рекомендациями от ibm и прочих по железу, настройкам и т.д. Потому что бывают системы, рассчитанные на тысячи рабочих мест, где толстый клиент не пойдет в принципе.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov ок, на ус намотал

Comment: Еще пару плюсов трехзвенки.

- Есть еще один аргумент - обновляемость и сопровождение. Гораздо проще подправить пару файлов и логики где-то сервере, чем обновлять толстый клиент у всех на рабочей машине в случае внесения изменений. Даже если меняется клиент, то хотя бы уже экономится объемы его обновления. 

- К тому же уменьшается количество возможных ошибок на клиентских машинах и упрощается их устранение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что-то меня смущает. Если был разработан толстый клиент, то для чего пришлось делать сервер с теми функциями, которые могли быть реализованы в толстом клиенте? Другими словами, люди делали трехуровневую архитектуру, но перемудрили. По идее, сервер должен нести бОльшую, если не вообще всю (если возможно), ношу бизнес-логики.

**Обновление**

Вы уже перечислили. А еще конфигурируемость в плюсы. Опять же, наличие бизнес-логики на клиенте увеличивает нагрузку на канал связи. Разработка тонкого клиента под различные платформы очевидно проще.

Answer (score 0):

Согласен с Nicolas Chabanovsky. Но хочу дополнить, что наличие бизнес-логики в толстом клиенте, возможно обусловлено с рисками - отсутствие связи?
Трехзвенную архитектуру поддерживать, по моему проще, бизнес-логика в одном месте, данные в другом, все логично, четко и понятно.

Как вариант, для того чтобы обойти указанный риск, при этом не использовать толстый клиент, это использование распределенной архитектуры. Т.е. установить сервера (сервер, БД)+тонкий клиент на каждом объекте информатизации. Собирает данные - центральный сервер.